# "Connection timed out" between Tomcat & Mysql

Tags: mysql, tomcat, socketexception

**Issue**
Socket Exception occurring when Tomcat sends request to Mysql.

This occurs around 10 times during a whole day. Since it is occurring rarely so, this seems to be a corner issue. Any inputs on how to debug it further/fix it?

**Setup Details**
Tomcat on Linux; 
Mysql

**Stacktrace**

`java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure: java.net.SocketException, underlying cause: Connection timed out`

**BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION**

`java.net.SocketException`

**MESSAGE**: Connection timed out

**STACKTRACE:**

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out

at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)

at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:146)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1392)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:1539)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1930)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1168)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1279)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQuery(MysqlIO.java:1225)

at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2278)

at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2225)

at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1163)

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)

at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractQueryReport$StatementProxy.invoke(AbstractQueryReport.ja

va:235)

at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.executeQuery(Unknown Source)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

**END NESTED EXCEPTION**

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:1714)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1930)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1168)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1279)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQuery(MysqlIO.java:1225)

at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2278)

at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2225)

at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1163)

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)

at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractQueryReport$StatementProxy.invoke(AbstractQueryReport.ja

va:235)

at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.executeQuery(Unknown Source)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Comment: are you able to connect to mysql atleast once? what i meant is are you facing "sometimes i'm able connect, sometimes i'm not issue"??

Comment: @FathahRehmanP:  Most of the times connection is successful. This issue occurs like around 10 times during a whole day. Very rare occurrence.

Comment: @MichaelMassey- i think my answer will solve your problem

Comment: Use a connection pooler like Hikari to handle your connections.

Comment: Hi @Stefan, Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool is being used to handle the connections.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure in your application you are closing connection after use. If you are not closing connection then after sometime it will reach max number of connection. After that you cant create connection. Only after reaching a timeout, mysql will close that connection(which you should close actually). After that you can use that connection. So kindly check your connection closing code.

Comment: Though I have checked the code quite a few times, let me check again and get back to you. Also, the DB Console shows that at max 20% of the allotted connections were used.

Answer (score 0):

The exception **java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out** could be because of many reasons.

But since you mention that you face it only some times during the day and it works fine normally, i think checking one of the two points below might help.

1. Check **wait_timeout** property of mysql. Check [this link](http://club.orbisius.com/howto/web-development/change-mysqls-wait_timeout-interactive_timeout-variables/)
2. Check **max_connections** property of mysql. Check [this link](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/update-max-connections-mysql/)

Comment: wait_timeout is 28800 seconds and max_connections is set to 1000

Comment: For max_connections, if there is a problem mysql returns "Too many connections", not "Connection timed out"